# Oracle - What TNS Names file am I using?

Tags: oracle, connection, tnsnames, tns

Sometimes I get Oracle connection problems because I can't figure out which tnsnames.ora file my database client is using.

What's the best way to figure this out?  ++happy for various platform solutions.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Oracle provides a utility called `tnsping`:

```
R:\>tnsping someconnection

TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 9.0.1.3.1 - Production on 27-AUG-20
08 10:38:07

Copyright (c) 1997 Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\Oracle92\network\ADMIN\sqlnet.ora
C:\Oracle92\network\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora

TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name

R:\>


R:\>tnsping entpr01

TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 9.0.1.3.1 - Production on 27-AUG-20
08 10:39:22

Copyright (c) 1997 Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\Oracle92\network\ADMIN\sqlnet.ora
C:\Oracle92\network\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora

Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (COMMUNITY = **)
 (PROTOCOL = TCP) (Host = ****) (Port = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = ENTPR0
1)))
OK (40 msec)

R:\>
```

This should show what file you're using. The utility sits in the Oracle `bin` directory.

Answer (score 22):

For linux:

```
$ strace sqlplus -L scott/tiger@orcl 2>&1| grep -i 'open.*tnsnames.ora'
```

shows something like this:

```
open("/opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora",O_RDONLY)=7
```

Changing to

```
$ strace sqlplus -L scott/tiger@orcl 2>&1| grep -i 'tnsnames.ora'
```

will show all the file paths that are failing.

Comment: Thanks, based on this, it looks like /etc/tnsnames.ora is a reliable, global location for tns names.

Comment: @AvindraGoolcharan, that is my conclusion as well.  That's where we put it and have had no problems.

Answer (score 5):

There is another place where the TNS location is stored: If you're using Windows, open `regedit` and navigate to `My HKEY Local Machine/Software/ORACLE/KEY_OraClient10_home1` where `KEY_OraClient10_home1` is your Oracle home. If there is a string entry called `TNS_ADMIN`, then the value of that entry will point to the TNS file that Oracle is using on your computer.

Answer (score 5):

On my development machine I have three different versions of Oracle client software. I manage the `tnsnames.ora` file in one of them. In the other two, I have entered in the `tnsnames.ora` file:

```
ifile=path_to_tnsnames.ora_file/tnsnames.ora
```

This way, if for some reason the wrong `tnsnames.ora` file is used by a client, it will always end up at the up-to-date version.

Answer (score 4):

For Windows: [Filemon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx) from SysInternals will show you what files are being accessed.

Remember to set your filters so you are not overwhelmed by the chatty file system traffic.

[image: Filter Dialog]

**Added:** Filemon does not work with newer Windows versions, so you might have to use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645).

Answer (score 4):

Codeslave asks "Shouldn't it always be "$ORACLE_ HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora"? The answer is no, it isn't. Consider these two invocations of tnsping on the same machine:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\me>D:\Oracle\10.2.0_DB\BIN\tnsping orcl

TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production on 09-OCT-2
008 14:30:12

Copyright (c) 1997,  2007, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
D:\Oracle\10.2.0_DB\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxxx
)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL)))

OK (40 msec)

C:\Documents and Settings\me>tnsping orcl

TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on 09-OCT-2
008 14:30:21

Copyright (c) 1997, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
D:\oracle\10.2.0_Client\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)
(HOST = XXXX)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL)))
OK (20 msec)

C:\Documents and Settings\me>
```

Note the two different parameter file locations, that are dependent on which tnsping executable you're running (and perhaps where it's being run from). For tnsnames-based oracle networking, using the TNS_ADMIN variable is the only way to ensure you're getting a consistent tnsnames.ora file.  (NOTE: Windows-centric answer)

Comment: Don't you just love multiple oracle homes?

Comment: Soooooo many +1's for this answer. It's been a few years since I've had to deal with this issue. The `TNS_ADMIN` environmental variable is the key. For PowerShell, it is `$env:TNS_Admin`. C# is `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TNS_Admin")`.

Answer (score 2):

By default, tnsnames.ora is located in the $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin directory on UNIX operating systems and in the ORACLE_HOME\network\admin directory on Windows operating systems. tnsnames.ora can also be stored the following locations:

The directory specified by the TNS_ADMIN environment variable (or registry value)

On UNIX operating systems, the global configuration directory. For example, on the Solaris Operating System, this directory is /var/opt/oracle

If you have multiple ORACLE_HOMES, be aware of which one you are using, as the location of the tnsnames.ora file can vary from one ORACLE_HOME to the next.

For the person who mentioned the TWO_TASK environment variable, that is used to set a default database service name to connect to (which could be a database on another server).  The service name you set TWO_TASK to is then looked up in the tnsnames.ora file when you connect.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it always be "$ORACLE_ HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora"?
Then you can just do "echo $oracle_ home" or the *nix equivalent.

@Pete Holberton
You are entirely correct. Which reminds me, there's another monkey wrench in the works called TWO_ TASK

According http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/TNS_ADMIN
TNS_ADMIN is an environment variable that points to the directory where the SQL*Net configuration files (like sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora) are located.

Comment: Actually, no, you cannot assume this location. There's the agent home and client home, just to name 2, that have their own network/admin directory. The answer you get depends on which executable you're running.

Answer (score 1):

`strace sqlplus -L scott/tiger@orcl` helps to find `.tnsnames.ora` file on `/home/oracle` to find the file it takes instead of `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora` file.   Thanks for the posting.

Answer (score 1):

Not direct answer to your question, but I've been quite frustrated myself trying find and update all of the tnsnames files, as I had several oracle installs: Client, BI tools, OWB, etc, each of which had its own oracle home. I ended up creating a utility called TNSNamesSync that will update all of the tnsnames in all of the oracle homes. It's under the MIT license, free to use here https://github.com/artybug/TNSNamesSync/releases

The docs are here:
https://github.com/artchik/TNSNamesSync/blob/master/README.md

This is for Windows only, though.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to check the **PATH** environment variable of the process that is connecting to the database. Most likely the tnsnames.ora file is in *first Oracle bin directory in path*..\network\admin. TNS_ADMIN environment variable or value in registry (for the current Oracle home) may override this.

Using filemon like suggested by others will also do the trick.