# ASP.NET to Oracle Database (ODP.NET): How do I specify which Oracle client to use?

Tags: asp.net, oracleclient

We have a web server with multiple oracle clients on it (8i, 9i, 10g). Both ODP.net 9.x and 10.x (and their oo4o counterparts) components are installed.

How do I specify to the web application which Oracle/ODP.net client to use when connecting to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some good info on this question here: [Oracle - What TNS Names file am I using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499/oracle-what-tns-names-file-am-i-using)

It looks like it all depends on which Oracle Home directory has priority in the the PATH.