# When using tnsping, can I specify a port number along with the SID?

Tags: oracle, tnsping

I use Bitvise Tunnelier to connect to a series of Oracle databases using SQL Developer; the connection is made to localhost and a specific port number, and this works fine.  I'd like to connect through other means (e.g., .NET), and I'm troubleshooting with tnsping.

Is there any way to run tnsping with a port number as well as the SID?  I've tried:

```
tnsping DatabaseSIDName:9001
tnsping DatabaseSIDName;9001
tnsping DatabaseSIDName,9001
```

All give "TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name".

Answer (score 8):

When you use tnsping, it will source some Oracle .ora files to determine what DBs it knows about. You should see something like:

```
$ tnsping myDB

TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on 24-MAY-2007 08:55:13
Copyright (c) 1997, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Used parameter files:
/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/network/admin/sqlnet.ora

Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact...
```

You can create your own tnsnames.ora file and add that to your `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable to add a new DB, port, SID, etc. A full example looks like:

```
ORA11 =
 (DESCRIPTION = 
  (ADDRESS_LIST =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 9001))
  )
 (CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVICE_NAME = DatabaseSIDName)
 )
)
```

Just `export TNS_ADMIN=<path to folder containing new tnsnames.ora file>` and attempt the ping again. Here are some references:

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora

[Oracle - What TNS Names file am I using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499/oracle-what-tns-names-file-am-i-using)

**EDIT**

---

And per your original example/follow up comment, the simplest might be:

```
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/tnsping <hostname>:<port>/<sid>
```

There are an abundance of other options, like EZConnect and sqlplus that will test the same functionality.

Comment: Is tnsping limited to entries in tnsnames?  I'd hoped to avoid touching it.